# Resolve $\mathbf{I}_{m} - \mathbf{X} \left( \mathbf{X}^{*} \mathbf{X} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{*} $.

Tags: matrices, regression, least-squares

Given a matrix $\mathbf{X}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times 2}_{2}$, a matrix of full column rank, which of the following elements completes a valid equality
$$
 \mathbf{I}_{m} - \mathbf{X} \left( 
 \mathbf{X}^{*} \mathbf{X}
\right)^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{*} = ?
$$

a) $\mathbf{I}_{m}$

b) $\mathbf{0}$

c) $\mathbf{M}$

d) None of the options will work.

I think the answer is $0$, since $ \left( 
 \mathbf{X}^{*} \mathbf{X}
\right)^{-1}=
\mathbf{X}^{−1}\left( \mathbf{X}^{*} \right)^{−1}$

But the answer is c) M ???

Comment: If $M$ exists then clearly $M=M$, but that is a little strange

Comment: Unless $n=2$, you cannot invert $X$

Comment: you can if you use generallized inverse.

Comment: @RwitamJana there is a reason why it is called *generalized* inverse. It isn't the inverse and doesn't have all the properties of the inverse.

Comment: Because the matrix $\mathbf{X}$ has full column rank, the pseuodinverse is a right-inverse 

$\mathbf{X}^{+} = \left( \mathbf{X} \mathbf{X}^{*} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{*} = \mathbf{X}^{-R}$

That is
$\mathbf{X} \mathbf{X}^{-R} = \mathbf{I}_{m}$

Therefore the identity in question distills down to this

$\mathbf{I}_{m} - \mathbf{X} \left( \mathbf{X} \mathbf{X}^{*} \right) \mathbf{X}^{*}  =
\mathbf{I}_{m} - \mathbf{X}  \mathbf{X}^{-R} = \mathbf{I}_{m} - \mathbf{I}_{m} = \mathbf{0}$

Answer (score 1):

Which of the following is $M$? And the the answer is $M$? Sounds tautological...

Anyway, $M - I - X'(X'X)^{-1}X'$ is the so called annihilator matrix. That is, $M$ is orthogonal projection onto $C(X)^\perp$ i.e., 
$$
My = y - Hy= y - \hat{y} = e .
$$ 
Your logic is falls as, in general, $n >2$, thus $X$ is non square matrix, hence $X^{-1}$ is undefined in the straightforward way and $\exists (X'X)^{-1}$ iff $rank(X'X)=2$.